# Reverse singly linked list - Code improvement

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to improve my recursion skills (or probably gain them for the first time :)). For it, I've written out a Java code to reverse a singly linked list, which is as follows:

```
node head, prev; // head is pointing to the start of the linked list

void reverselist(node current) {
    if (current.next != null) {
        reverselist(current.next);
    }
    if (current.next == null) {
        this.head = current;
        prev = current;
    }
    else {
        prev.next = current;
        current.next = null;
        prev = current;
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but for learning's sake, I want to avoid using global variable (node prev) for operations inside the recursive function. So can this function be re-written to avoid it completely? Any other optimizations are welcome :)

Comment: This is more a question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have a private member in all of my linked lists that point to the firstNode, maybe that would work for you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better implementation should be as below:

```
public Node reverse(Node current)
{
 if (current== null || current.next==null) return current;
 Node nextItem = current.next;
 current.next = null;
 Node reverseRest = reverse(nextItem);
 nextItem.next = current;
 return reverseRest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Linkedlist reverseList (LinkedList list) {

    Node temp = null;
    Node nextNode = list;
    while(list != null) {
        nextNode = list.next;
        list.next = temp;
        temp = list;
        list = nextNode;
    }
    return temp;
}

private class LinkedList {

    int data;
    LinkedList next;
}
```

Comment: please try to add comments / explanation to the post you added in answer... this will help other to understand quickly.